# How can I restrict 'edit_form_after_' to a specific post/page?

Tags: admin

Is there a way in which I can use '[edit_form_after_](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2012/12/01/more-hooks-on-the-edit-screen/)' to display a message solely on the admin screen of a specific post ID or title?

The basic 'add message' code I use is below:

```
function add_new_screen_message() {

$screen = get_current_screen();

if ( $screen->post_type=='page' && $screen->id=='page') {

echo "new test message";
}
}
add_action( 'edit_form_after_editor', 'add_new_screen_message' );
```

After the 'use the first argument $post' suggestion, none of my various efforts worked and so I haven't included them here.

Comment: you can use the first argument `$post`, look in the code : https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.9.5/src/wp-admin/edit-form-advanced.php#L667

Comment: @mmm Thanks. Relatively inexperienced, I'm searching for more info... so far, I've not been able to avoid an error of 'unexpected '-''.

Comment: That would just be a syntax error in the PHP. If you include the code you tried it will be possible to point out the issue.

Comment: @Jacob Peattie  Thanks. I've added my normal code to the original question, but minus the unsuccessful attempts to modify it according to the earlier comment suggestion.